# Datatables very slow in IE but fast in chrome

Tags: jquery, client, datatables

I have this datatable which looks nice but takes whole 4 seconds to render in IE. In chrome it's very fast.
I know that the speed issue is not because of the server side, as the ajax response gets to the client in less then 0.5 seconds. It's returning only 21 rows.
Am I doing something wrong or datatables is just slow?

Thanks.

```
            $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "GetData.asmx/GetEventMembers",
            //data: {ShulID: iShulID, EventID: iEventID},
            data: "{'ShulID': '" + iShulID
            + "','EventID': '" + iEventID + "'}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            //sAjaxDataProp: "",
            success: function (jsonRes) 
            {

                var oTable = $('#tblEventMembers').dataTable({
                    "bDestroy": true,
                    "bJQueryUI": true,
                    "bProcessing": true,
                    "bDeferRender": true,
                    "bPaginate": false,
                    "sScrollY": "200px", 
                    "aaData": $.parseJSON(jsonRes.d).aaData,
                    "aoColumns": [
                                    { "mData": "MemberID" },
                                    { "mData": "FName" },
                                    { "mData": "LName" },
                                    { "mData": "InvitationDate" },
                                    { "mData": "Approved" },
                                    { "mData": "Invited" }
                                 ]
                });
            },
            failure: function (msg) {
                alert(msg);
            }
        });
```

Comment: Add `"bSortClasses": false` and get rid of `"bDestroy": true`

Comment: Didn't do it. Still very slow.

Comment: Also just a suggestion :) Even though datatables can take some times to render, you should never get that delay with 21 rows. Another thing that spring to my eyes : Why `$.parseJSON(jsonRes.d).aaData`? It seems completely unnessecary, you are already ensured valid JSON in success by `dataType: "json"`. Try `jsonRes.d.aaData` instead (or however your json structure is)

Comment: When i removed the $.parseJson i got this error: JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'length' of undefined or null reference

Comment: Now i see that it's only slow in IE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After trying everything under the sun, I finally solved the problem.
IE is only slow then you use VS to debug your website. Just by running the website by clicking the play button, it's slow.
When I surf the website without the debugger, it runs very good.

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for this.  I can't believe what a different it made by not attaching the debugger.